# What is a UIView appears before UITableViewWrapperView when pull to down?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Who can explain?
I have **ViewController** with **TableView**. I want set another background color with image to **View** of **ViewController**, like: `self.view.backgroundColor = someColor`, and it's ok. But when I pull **TableView** to down some **UIView** appears before  **UITableViewWrapperView** in hierarchy:

[image: Some view]

Pull to down:

[image: Pull to down]
[image]

If I make pull to up this magic **View** doesn't appears and it looks as I'm expecting:
[image]
[image]

What I did try to do:

```
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // doesn't work
tableView.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // doesn't work
tableView.subviews.first?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

It was **UIView** from **UISearchController**...